# Service Fabric - Warning: Failed to create infrastructure coordinator

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have deployed a SB using ARM-Templates and when I go to the explorer it shows all nodes are healthy, but on the system tree my 2 node types have a warning saying:

> Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.InfrastructureService',
>   Property='CoordinatorStatus', HealthState='Warning',
>   ConsiderWarningAsError=false. Failed to create infrastructure
>   coordinator:
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Management.DeploymentManagementEndpointNotFoundException:
>   Could not find the deployment management endpoint: ManagementUri    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Management.DeploymentManagementServer.CreateChannelFactory()
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Management.DeploymentManagementServer.Initialize(IDeploymentManagementServer
>   server)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Management.DeploymentManagementClient..ctor(IDeploymentManagementServer
>   server)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Management.DeploymentManagementClient.CreateInstanceImpl(IDeploymentManagementServer
>   server)    at
>   System.Fabric.InfrastructureService.ManagementClientFactory.Create()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.InfrastructureService.WindowsAzureInfrastructureCoordinatorFactory.Create()
>   at
>   System.Fabric.InfrastructureService.ServiceFactory.CreateCoordinatorByReflection(String
>   assemblyName, String factoryTypeName, Object[]
>   factoryCreateMethodArgs)    at
>   System.Fabric.InfrastructureService.DelayLoadCoordinator.d__c.MoveNext()

.....any idea??? I would really appreciate it

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It could be possible that your ARM template has a mismatch on the durabilityLevel setting. There are 2 places it needs to be set for each node type. 
a. VM extension resource section 
b. Service Fabric cluster resource section.

Could you please check if both of those sections have the same value for each node type. E.g. "durabilityLevel": "Gold"

Comment: If there is a mismatch and you are just trying to create and try out a new Service Fabric cluster, the easiest way to fix it is to delete the resource group and redeploy the ARM template. Of course, this assumes that you don't have any useful workload on the cluster yet.